# Texture of sprite not changing after running animation in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit

The code below runs an animation and, upon completion, runs the resetBall function.

Why is the line (ball.texture = normalTexture) not working? (adding self. in front of it does not resolve the issue)

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
    func resetBall() {
        ballDying = false
        let normalTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "Ball1")
        ball.texture = normalTexture
        self.ball.position = CGPoint(x: -120, y: 40)
    }

    var ballDying = false

    override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
        if ((map_1_buffer.contains(ball.position)) == false) && !ballDying {
            ballDying = true
            let texture1 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "death_1")
            let texture2 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "death_2")
            let texture3 = SKTexture(imageNamed: "death_3")
            let deathAnimation = SKAction.animate(with: [texture1, texture2, texture3], timePerFrame: 1)
            self.ball.run(deathAnimation, completion: resetBall)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the update method approach it's not the best way to do this. Remember the documentation about the update function: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skscenedelegate/1519757-update?language=objc

> **Do not call this method directly**; it is called by the system exactly
>   once per frame, so long as the scene is presented in a view and is not
>   paused. This is the first method called when animating the scene,
>   before any actions are evaluated and before any physics are simulated.

Try to avoid put complex code on the update function.

Now, for texture problem probably can be solved using

```
let normalTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "blueBall")
ball?.run(SKAction.setTexture(normalTexture))
```

You can see the complete example here: https://github.com/Maetschl/SpriteKitExamples/blob/master/BouncingBalls/BouncingBalls/GameScene.swift

Comment: thank you for the quick response! Your code fixed my issue. I will read the documentation you suggested to design my game more effectively.